# LDAP - Meaning of objectClass = top

Tags: ldap

I was dealing with some LDAP entries and I am wondering myself why "objectClass = top" is always a part of each entry. According to the internet this stands for the highest level any objectClass, but why is it there in any entry?

An example can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/de/SSRMWJ_6.0.0.4/com.ibm.isim.doc_6.0.0.4/securing/tsk/tsk_ic_cognos_create_users_in_ldap.htm).

Comment: Because it is the highest level object class, the base-most base class of all LDAP object classes.

Answer (score 12):

`top` is an abstract object class that is the parent of every LDAP object class. It is the one that defines that every object in LDAP must have an `objectClass` attribute.